# Elif statement Misbehaving and open desktop.ini again and again. Why?

Tags: python, windows, if-statement, desktop.ini

This code is misbehaving and I don't know why. It executes, again and again, the same elif statement without any input and return the desktop.ini file, please tell me how can i fix this and why is this happening. If i put only 5 or 6 elif statements then its work fine but after 6th statement its not work or start misbehaving.
desktop.ini file code is

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21790
InfoTip=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-12689
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-108
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll
IconIndex=-237


import pyttsx3
import wikipedia
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import webbrowser
import datetime

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if 0 <= hour < 12:
        speak("Good Morning!")

    elif 12 <= hour < 18:
        speak("Good Afternoon!")

    else:
        speak("Good Evening!")

    speak("I am your assistant Sir. Please tell me how may I help you")

def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        # print(e)
        print("Say that again please...")
        return "None"
    return query


def wikipedia(query):
    speak('Searching Wikipedia...')
    query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
    results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
    speak("According to Wikipedia")
    print(results)
    speak(results)


def youtube():
    webbrowser.open("youtube.com")


def ongoogle(query):
    if "search" in query:
        query = query.replace("search", "")
    query = query.replace("on google", "")
    webbrowser.open(f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query}")


def google():
    webbrowser.open("google.com")


def yahoo():
    webbrowser.open("yahoo.com")


def music():
    music_dir = 'your path'
    songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
    print(songs)
    os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[0]))


def musicyt():
    webbrowser.open(
        "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvyUuxdRdR4&list=RDCLAK5uy_n9Fbdw7e6ap-98_A- 
8JYBmPv64v-Uaq1g&start_radio=1")


def thetime():
    strTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    speak(f"Sir, the time is {strTime}")


def vscode():
    codePath = "your path"
    os.startfile(codePath)


def pycharm():
    codePath = "your path"
    os.startfile(codePath)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    wishMe()
    while True:
        # if 1:
        query = takeCommand().lower()
        if 'wikipedia' in query:
            wikipedia(query)

        elif 'open youtube' in query:
            youtube()

        elif 'on google' in query:
            ongoogle(query)

        elif 'open google' in query:
            google()

        elif 'open yahoo' in query:
            yahoo()

        elif 'play music' or 'play song' or 'play songs' in query:
            music()

        elif 'play music on youtube' or 'play song on youtube' or 'play songs on youtube' in query:
            musicyt()

        elif 'the time' in query:
            thetime()

        elif 'open vscode' in query:
            vscode()

        elif 'open pycharm' in query:
            pycharm()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
elif 'play music' or 'play song' or 'play songs' in query:
```

is probably not evaluated the way you think. The first two conditions just evaluate to the strings `'play music'` and `'play song'`. Only the third part of the condition is checking to see if a value is in `query`.

You need to check that each string is in the `query` variable.

```
elif 'play music' in query or 'play song' in query or 'play songs' in query:
```

Comment: it's solved my problem. this is so helpful for me.